# Does sustaining Mountain's Might allow an extra attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

The Level 9 Shaman power Mountain's Might[<sup>DDI</sup>](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12875) (Dark Sun Campaign Setting) does the following:

> **Primary Target**: One ally
>
> **Effect**: Your spirit companion disappears. Until the end of your next turn, the primary target assumes the form of mountain’s might. While in this form, the primary target is slowed, gains resist 5 to all damage, and gains a power bonus to melee damage rolls equal to your Intelligence modifier. The primary target can end the effect as a minor action. Make an attack that is a close burst 1 centered on the primary target.
>
> > **Secondary Target**: Each enemy in the burst
> >     **Attack**: Wisdom vs. Fortitude
> >     **Hit**: 2d6 + Wisdom modifier damage, and the secondary target falls prone.
> >     **Miss**: Half damage.
>
> **Sustain Minor**: The form of mountain’s might persists.

If you spend a minor action to sustain the power, I assume this means you sustain the effect on the ally (slowed, resist 5 all, +int melee damage).

If you sustain does it also allow you to make another close burst 1 centered on the primary target?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### No.

The Mountain's Might form is something separate to the burst attack. The Sustain persists the form, and does not mention repeating the burst attack.

Contrast this to Furious Immolation<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12558)</sup>, a Master of Flame attack from Dragon Magazine 388. It creates a zone and comes with a secondary burst attack just like Mountain's Might does, and its Sustain Minor reads: *"The zone persists until the end of your next turn, and you repeat the secondary attack."*

Comment: Further, note that in Mountain's Might, the effects of the form are described, then target's ability to end the form is described, then the attack is mentioned. The implication being that the attack is not part of the form.

Comment: I wonder if there's any reason to read the power such that the attack occurs only when the form is ended by that minor action?

Comment: @Soulrift I could definitely seeing that be a reading of the power, but the sentences structure suggests that the attack is separate from the condition, not contingent on it ending.